# setTimeout Node v0.12 fires immediately in for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Out of all the questions I have seen on this site about setTimeout the majority of them people are executing the method in a setTimeout declaration. I am not doing this.

Code:

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

for(var i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function(num){
    var url = getUrl(num);
    //query(url); // prints out query operation and data return
    console.log(num);
  }, 1000, nums[i]);
}
```

When running the command to start the app, query will execute all items in the array no matter how large I set the millisecond delay. When running this code with printing out to console I get the same effect. Am I doing this wrong? Can anyone else duplicate this?

I created an app that would run setInterval to test api throttling, and it works as expected. I am thinking I may be missing some kind of backend knowledge about node with setTimeout and loops? [setTimeout Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg)

The docs do say that it won't guarantee the time that it will execute the callback, but I have 120 items that it is going to fire logging on and it fires them all at once.

Comment: That's what you ask it to do: it would evaluate all 9 calls after 1 second.

Comment: You're configuring 9 `setTimeout()` calls that are all set to fire 1 second from now.

Comment: Ah, alright that would make more sense as to why people are multiplying the index by the delay amount.

Answer (score 0):

since those function `setTimeout` or `setInterval` works asynchronously,
You have to call the next loop in the setTimeout/setInterval callback function.

```
var _i = 0
var doQuery = setInterval(function(){
  if(_i == nums.length) clearInterval(doQuery);
  var url = getUrl(nums[_i]);
  query(url);
  _i++;
},1000);
```